# base() constructor in C#'s custom exception handling. How does it work?

Tags: c#, exception

I am learning exception handling, particularly exception handling on C# (I know, not the best idea). I found that base() method(?) is used in creating custom exceptions. While I managed to create a custom exception, I am not sure why it works.

```
class Calculator
{
    public int power(int n, int p)
    {
        if(n < 0 || p < 0)
        {
            throw (new Exp("n and p should be non-negative"));
        }

        return (int)Math.Pow(n, p);

    }
}

public class Exp : System.Exception
{
    public Exp(string message) : base(message)
    {
        //Nothing here
    }
```

}

Calculator.power(n, p) is tasked with returning an n raised to the p power. If either n or p are negative, it throws an exception.

What I do not get is why Exp("n and p should be non-negative") prints the message. There is no base constructor in the exception class that returns a string.

The only constructor that exists in Exp class has nothing in it. And yet, if I pass a string into that constructor method, it prints.

What is happening?

Comment: Maybe ToString() is called on exception - Console did it automatically.

Comment: I hope your doing best practice and creating three constructors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Exception(string)` constructor overload simply stores the passed parameter into a field exposed by the `Exception.Message` property. You can see this by looking at the [reference source for Exception](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/exception.cs,65) to make it clearer.

`Message` property is used inside the `Exception.ToString()` method (here is the [source for that](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/exception.cs,65)) when creating a string representation of the exception.

However, this message is not automatically "printed" anywhere. This is done by the CLR when it detects the unhandled exception; it catches the exception, calls `.ToString()`, prints the string to the console, and ends your application.

You can easily see that no printing is done by constructing the `Exception` by catching the exception yourself:

```
try 
{
    var x = new Calculator().power(-1, -2);
}
catch (Exp e)
{
   // do nothing
}
```

Apart from that:

1. Try to follow C# naming conventions. Methods are pascal cased in C#.
2. Custom exceptions usually have the `Exception` suffix. In your case you don't even need a custom exception, you should throw an `ArgumentException` or an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`:

   ```
   class Calculator
   {
       public int Power(int n, int p)
       {
           if (n < 0)
               throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(n), "n must be positive");

           if (p < 0)
               throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(p), "p must be positive");

           return (int)Math.Pow(n, p);
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

`base()` is used not just in creating custom exceptions but in any inheritance situation.  Your custom exception inherits from `System.Exception` and pass its constructor argument `message` to the base class's constructor via the `base` call - see [base reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx) for more detail.

The behavior you are seeing with the printout is because your custom exception has inherited `System.Exception`'s implementation of `.ToString()`.  See [System.Exception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception(v=vs.110).aspx) and the [Exception(message) constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/48ca3hhw(v=vs.110).aspx) for a further explanation of the behavior for that class.

But it's important to understand that this use of `base` is not special with exceptions - this is the same for any class inheritance - but not all base classes will provide such a useful implementation of `ToString()`!

Answer (score 1):

When .NET process exits due unhandled exception, the exception is printed to console automatically. If you catch the exception, nothing will be printed out.